# Create a separate column of list of all the purchases except the first occurrence in python pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

My data looks like below :

```
Customer Date Product 
c1       D1   p1
c1       D2   p2 
c1       D3   p3
c2       D4   p1
c2       D5   p2
```

I want my output to look like following :

```
Customer list_of_products_excluding_the_first_purchase     find_p3
c1       [p2,p3]                                           yes
c2       [p2]                                              no
```

Basically, I grouped by customers and put all the purchases except first purchase as a separate column. And then finding if p3 exists in the second column, if it exists , flag it as yes

Answer (score 1):

First get all values without first by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with[`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then create lists per groups:

```
s = df[df['Customer'].duplicated()].groupby('Customer')['Product'].apply(list)
```

Or use lambda function with [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) and convert to `lists`:

```
s = df.groupby('Customer')['Product'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:].tolist())
#alternative
#s = df.groupby('Customer')['Product'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()[1:])
```

---

```
df = s.reset_index(name='list_of_products_excluding_the_first_purchase')
print (df)
  Customer list_of_products_excluding_the_first_purchase
0       c1                                      [p2, p3]
1       c2                                          [p2]
```

EDIT: You can add new column `find_p3` for test `p3` values and change aggregation with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test if at least one True per groups. Last if necessary use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set `yes` and `no`:

```
df1 = (df[df['Customer'].duplicated()].assign(find_p3 = lambda x: x['Product'] == 'p3')
      .groupby('Customer')
      .agg({'Product':list, 'find_p3':'any'})
      .reset_index())
df1['find_p3'] = np.where(df1['find_p3'], 'yes', 'no')

print (df1)
  Customer   Product find_p3
0       c1  [p2, p3]     yes
1       c2      [p2]      no
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['Customer'].duplicated())
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Customer, dtype: bool

print (df[df['Customer'].duplicated()])
  Customer Date Product
1       c1   D2      p2
2       c1   D3      p3
4       c2   D5      p2
```

Solution with chnaged columns names in pandas 0.25+:

```
df1 = (df[df['Customer'].duplicated()].assign(find_p3 = lambda x: x['Product'] == 'p3')
      .groupby('Customer')
      .agg(list_of_products_excluding_the_first=('Product', list),
           testp3 =('find_p3', 'any'))
      .reset_index())
df1['testp3'] = np.where(df1['testp3'], 'yes', 'no')
print (df1)
  Customer list_of_products_excluding_the_first testp3
0       c1                             [p2, p3]    yes
1       c2                                 [p2]     no
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, and what if I want another column where i have to check whether p2 was there in the list created or not and flag it as 1 if it was found for each customer

Comment: @Mighty - Can you check data sample for new column?

Comment: @Jazrael , its very slow on 35 lac records , any tips ?

Comment: @Mighty - first solution should be fastest

Comment: @Jazrael , i wonder how .duplicated would remove the first occurrence ?

Comment: @Mighty - by `df[df['Customer'].duplicated()]` - it remove all first dupes